# How to get cost of Azure subscription programmatically

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

Trying to understand the different Azure APIs to get the Azure subscription cost details programmatically.
I see [RateCard API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/manage/consumption-api-overview) is good approach. In the output/response of this API , there is something called meterID and meterDetails.

anyone know what is this meterID and meterDetails ? how to get it using Azure Portal ?

Comment: I think you can look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/consumption/usagedetails/list#modernusagedetail) https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTiPh.png

Comment: Thanks. From where you get this page ?

Comment: I provided the doc in the comment, click 'this' and search for 'meterID'. This property appears in many cost management apis, so I think they have the same meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meterID is a `GUID` for every resource except VMs. meterDetails is the detailed Usage. You can get these details from the cost management section in Azure portal

Comment: You mean , cost management section of Subscription ? I just went to cost analysis under cost management of subscription but did not find any . Can you please elaborate ?